# LSZ reduction for Bhabha scattering

Tags: quantum-field-theory, hilbert-space, quantum-electrodynamics, s-matrix-theory

This may be a silly question. As far as I know, the LSZ reduction formula is an equation to relate S-matrix elements and the expectation value of the time-ordered field operator. This approach allows us to calculate S-matrix elements non-perturbatively for massive particles.

In QED, photon is massless, so we cannot calculate S-matrix elements using the LSZ formula in general processes(in a rigorous sense). But for the Bhabha scattering, since both the initial and final state are massive particles, can we apply the LSZ formula to calculate the S-matrix elements for Bhabha scattering in a rigorous way?